# cURLpp Send JSON with GET request

Tags: c++, json, get, curlpp

I tried to send a GET request (to https://api.binance.com/api/v3/depth) but I can't seem to find how to send a JSON payload with it.
I found this:

```
std::string body;
body = "{\"symbol\":\"BTCUSDT\",\"limit\":5}";

request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::HttpHeader(header));
request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::PostFields(body));
request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::PostFieldSize(body.length()));
```

But this seems to convert the request to a POST (understandably) and if I make it a GET again with

```
request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Post(0));
```

it just ignores the previously set fields.

Note: I could include the info in the URL but I specifically want to know if it's possible to send a JSON.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to add before `request.perform();`:

```cpp
request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::CustomRequest("GET"));
```